# Visual Studio Code and Unreal Engine

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, header-files

I am just starting to mess around with C++ and have no experience so, please explain it like to a toddler.

I am trying to setup Visual Studio Code (v1.79.2) to work with Unreal 5.2.1. OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19044

I downloaded all the necessary tools, i set up a project in unreal, i modified the c_cpp_properties.json to include the folders containing the headers, yet when i am trying to save the project i get the following error:

```
#include errors detected. Consider updating your compile_commands.json or includePath. IntelliSense features for this translation unit (E:\My Work\Sailors\Source\Sailors\Private\Sailors.cpp) will be provided by the Tag Parser.

cannot open source file "Sailors.h"
```

this is how my c_cpp_properties looks like:

```
    {
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "SailorsEditor Editor Win64 Development (Sailors)",
            "compilerPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community\\VC\\Tools    \\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\Hostx64\\x64\\cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x64",
            "configurationProvider": "epic.ue",
            "compileCommands": "E:\\My Work\\Sailors\\.vscode\\compileCommands_Sailors.json",
            "includePath": [ 
            "${workspaceFolder}\\Intermediate\\**", 
            "${workspaceFolder}\\Plugins\\**", 
            "${workspaceFolder}\\Source\\**",
            "E:\\Games\\Epic\\UE_5.2\\Engine\\Source\\Runtime\\Core\\Public" ],
            
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE",
                "__UNREAL__", 
                "UBT_COMPILED_PLATFORM=Windows", 
                "WITH_ENGINE=1", 
                "WITH_UNREAL_DEVELOPER_TOOLS=1", 
                "WITH_APPLICATION_CORE=1", 
                "WITH_COREUOBJECT=1" 
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
    }
```

Note that I separated the C++(.cpp) and header files (.h) into separate directories and updated the compileCommands_xxx.json accordingly.

Any ideas? I've been searching for a solution for a couple of days now but none of the offered ones are working for me or maybe i just fail to understand and do them properly.

I tried including the direct folder links to the c_ccp_properties.jsaon but it did not help.
Tried starting a new project - same issue.
Restarted Visual Studio Code multiple times (i saw some people telling that it might be due to stored cache)

Comment: Use Visual Studio 2022, not Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases if you have valid compilation database (compileCommands*.json) the C++ extension will attempt to use that. All the extra includes and defines UE tells you to add are for the fallback in the case that the C++ extension can't find what it is looking for in the database. I don't know why the documentation states to add that stuff as Unreal will clear it all out when you refresh the project, which you need to do whenever you add a new class.

A common misconception with the VSCode C++ extension is what exactly the configs in the c_cpp_properties file is for. They are purely for letting the extension know how to understand your code. They are not compilation instructions for the build tasks. They do not alter the underlying project (in this case the UE project) in any way. Adding an include path to the config in c_cpp_properties is not the same as adding it to the Unreal project.

I suspect there are two possible causes for your issue:

1. You added a new class C++ to your project and forgot to refesh the code project in Unreal Editor (Tools -> Refresh project). This will update the compilation database to include your new class. There doesn't seem to be a way to tell Unreal to do this automatically whenever you create a new class unfortunately.

and/or

2. You didn't correct the #include path in the Sailors.cpp file when you separated the .h and .cpp files into separate folders. The error says it is can't find "Sailors.h" from "Sailors.cpp". They are not in the same folder anymore so it will not be able to find Sailors.h. If you tried to build the project I suspect it would fail, which tells you that it is a compiler issue not an issue with the extension.

Here is a simplified verson of how include lookups work:

Lets say our file structure is

```
MyProjectFolder
 |-src
   |-MyFile.cpp
 |-inc
   |-MyFile.h
 |-AnotherFile.h
```

If you are in MyFile.cpp and use #include "MyFile.h", it will fail.
When you use #include "MyFile.h" it will look for the file 3 ways.

1. Relative to the file that included it (which is why MyFile.h works from MyFile.cpp if they are in the same folder). Similar to many command line apps you can use ../ to go up a directory. So ../MyFile.h would look in MyProjectFolder and ../inc/MyFile.h would look in MyProjectFolder/inc/.
2. Relative to project defined include paths. So if in your C++ project you the include path "MyProjectFolder/" you would be able to do #include "inc/MyFile.h" as it will also do a search relative to MyProjectFolder/. Be aware that adding an include path to the list in the c_cpp_properties config is not the same as addding it to the project itself. It will fix the extension warning but the project will fail to compile.
3. Absolute paths, if the path is absolute (i.e C:/my/file/path.h) that will work, but you generally want to avoid this as the path is likely to be different on other machines.

There are other types of includes such as <> includes that do other lookups but they aren't really relevant here.